# Perfectly orientate an object based on two vector3?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Make a basic cylinder game object and set it's scale to (0.01, 10, 0.01).  It should look like an upright stick.

What I would like to do (in c#) is dynamically position and rotate this stick based on only two vector3.   The first would be FROM and represents the bottom most point of the stick, and TO is the top most part of the stick.

If there is already built in methods that can do this GREAT but after experimenting with all sorts of methods in Transform and Quaternion I can't seem to get this perfect.

Comment: I think I understand what your question is, and I've done something similar before. The steps I took: 1) Calculate distance between the two Vector3 positions, 2) Scale cylinder so that its height matches that distance, 3) Calculate Quaternion rotation necessary to rotate from cylinder's starting orientation (eg. Vector3.up) to match the Vector3 connecting the two positions, 4) Rotate the cylinder using this calculated Quaternion, 5) Position the cylinder at the average between the two positions (assuming its pivot point is centered). Let me know if you need a working example as an answer.

Comment: This is precisely what I'm trying to achieve.. and I've been going in circles trying to get it to work right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, scale the stick to fit between the two points (vectors) `a` and `b`. Halve the distance to get the scale, because the cube is 2 units tall.

```
stick.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.01, 0.01, (a - b).magnitude * 0.5f);
```

Then position the stick's center between the two points.

```
stick.transform.position = (a + b) * 0.5f;
```

Then rotate the stick.

```
stick.transform.LookAt(b);
```

If you actually have a model, you might notice that the stick's oriented the wrong way. Unity uses +Z as forward by convention. You can fix that by rotating the stick as a last step or putting the model in a child transform of the stick and rotating the model so that +Z is forward. If the stick isn't centered in the right place, it might be because the origin isn't at the center of the model or the model isn't the right width. You can solve this the same way as orientation, or modify the code.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you are trying to do, stop and use the [line renderer](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDoQtwIwBGoVChMI-M7O1bfqxwIV0EmSCh0KXQUm&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DaRMsHY1-NZI&usg=AFQjCNEdHz5IdP2R0L9958BjLu86ak6qCA&sig2=Y8SESp1GwJMIhJJCNnFSJw&bvm=bv.102022582,d.aWw)

Comment: This is pretty cool and thanks for enlightening me on this!  However this won't suite my needs since I'll eventually be using real 3d models instead of my simple stick that was mentioned above.